# iPhone Status Bar Style

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is it possible to change the status bar to a certain style in different views.  I have two views, each a different theme.  Right now I have the status bar to black, but let's say on a certain view I want it gray.  Is it possible, if so how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:... animated:YES];
```

Comment: Would this be placed in the viewdidload method of the view?

Comment: No, `viewWillAppear:` is the better place. Remember that `viewDidLoad` will not get called every time a view is pushed on screen, but only if it isn't yet in memory. In addition, the `animated` argument of `viewWillAppear:` can nicely be passed on to the status bar method.